# How can I combine tables and edit some of the results?

Tags: sql

I have two tables from a chat application

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
uid int PRIMARY KEY,
name text,
phone text);

CREATE TABLE Messages(
recipient int REFERENCES Users(uid),
sender int REFERENCES Users(uid),
time timestamp NOT NULL,
message text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (recipient, sender, time)
);
```

how can I find how many messages have been sent by users with a phone that starts for example 250?
and also how can I find the names of the users that have sent more messages than have received?

thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior during GROUP BY is different amoung the various DB manufacturers.

The Users.id is part of the GROUP BY, and the count() is an aggregator, so those fields are OK.  Users.name may be a problem, as the system may not be able to tell if the value is unique.  In that case, do "MIN(Users.name)" which is a function that returns a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the below query that include 
table2 inner  join table1 as you want 
 senders with count of messages sent which are mainly in table t2.

Further, you require sender which is recipent as well but count of messages specific to each sender should be greater than it has received

```
       Select t2.sender,
      t2.count(*) 
      from table2  t2
      inner join table1 t1 on
      t2.sender=t1.uid and 
      t2.recipent=t1.uid where
       t1.phone like '250%' group by 
       t2.sender having t2.sender IN
       Select recipent from (Select 
          recipent, count(*) from table2 
         group by recipent
         having count(*)<t2.count(*))
```

Answer (score -1):

for the first part of your question you can use this simple method and it works good
SELECT COUNT(*) groupofpeople
FROM Users
WHERE phone LIKE '250%';